# puts vs printf in the following code?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

int main(void)
{

        if(printf("ABC"))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            printf("XYZ");
        }
        _getch();
        return 0;
}

output : ABC

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

int main(void)
{

        if(puts("ABC"))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            printf("XYZ");
        }
        _getch();
        return 0;
}

output : ABC XYZ
```

(IDE : MSVC++)
what is the difference between printf and puts in if statement in above 2 programs??

Comment: ^^^^ Thank you for your generosity and support ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `printf` returns the number of character written
- `puts` returns a non-negative value in case of success

As a result :

- In the first code, `printf` returns a positive value which evaluates to `true`, the `else` branch is never executed, thus printing `ABC` only
- In the second code, `puts` most likely succeeds and returns 0 which evaluates to `false`, the `else` branch gets executed, thus printing both `ABC` and `XYZ`

As pointed out by others, `puts` will also append a newline while `printf` won't.

Answer (score 3):

`puts()` appends a newline and returns a different value (non-negative [which could include 0] on success, -1 on failure).

Comment: means puts write the "ABC" then because of success it returns 0 and then 0 means false in C,C++ then it execute else block and then print wt is return in else block ?? m i correct ..

Comment: It *could* return 0. Or it could return something else. The only sure thing you can do is compare the return value with `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` returns the number of characters printed (so when successfully printing a non-empty strong, the return value is not 0 and thus true in a boolean context), while `puts` simply returns a non-negative number to indicate success (which might very well be 0 aka false).

Answer (score 0):

[printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) on success returns the number of characters written which in your case is `3`.

[puts](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/puts/) on success returns a non-negative number which could also be `0`. Looks like it returned a `0` in your case making the else part to execute.